# What does 気持がある mean?

Tags: meaning

I know sometimes 気持 can be used to express a good feeling or sensation, but what about other feelings ? By the way, the sentence i found was 彼女に成功して欲しいっていう気持ちもあるけど、正直、帰って欲しくない

I think it's something like "I also want her to have success, but i don't want her to go home"

Thank you all!

:)

Answer (score 6):

> 「彼女{かのじょ}に成功{せいこう}して欲{ほ}しいっていう気持{きも}ちもあるけど、正直{しょうじき}、帰{かえ}って欲{ほ}しくない。」

「気持ちがある」 in this particular context means "***there is a part of me that wants to***".

By changing the 「が」 to a 「も」, the baisc meaning stays pretty much the same, but it would suggest that you actually have another (opposing) desire as well.

> "There is a part of me that wants her to be successful, but if I were to be honest, I would not want to see her return home."